# Unable to GitLab after changing the ExternalUrl parameter in gitlab.rb

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, gitlab

here is a what we tried to do. We installed GitLab few weeks ago with a FQDN, say xyz.company.com as the ExternalUrl. We used the software for last couple of weeks and everything was working just fine except for the SSL error at the time of login. Just today we tried to change the ExternalUrl from **xyz.company.com** to **abc.company.net** and we tried to add the firms certificate to the **trusted-certs** folder. We reconfigured GitLab and after that we cant connect to GitLab anymore. We are getting a "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error.

Any ideas what could be going on?

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: Please specify whether you cannot connect to GitLab with a webbrowser or with a git client.

Comment: From the web browser. I haven't tried connecting from the client actually.

Comment: In that case, I guess it is a problem with your webserver configuration. To debug that, more information (the relevant parts of the webserver config files, log files etc.) is needed.

Comment: Thawn, it turns out the SSL .crt and .key files were corrupted. When I checked the status of the services, gitlab-ctl status, we noticed that nginx was down. Then when we checked the log file, the error messages hinted at some problem with the SSL certificate and key. For now I disabled SSL while we figure the issue with the certificate. Thanks.